# Cancel Promise.all update MongoDB when one reject

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have two Model: User and Project.

```
User: name, projects [ { id, role } ]
Project: name, members []
```

I wrote a function to add a member (from User) to Project. My code:

```
const addMember = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { userId, role, projectId } = req.body
    Promise.all([
        Project.findByIdAndUpdate(projectId, { $push: {members: userId}}),
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { $push: {projects: { id: userId, role: role}} })
    ]).then(values => {
        if (!values[0] || !values[1]) return next("Can not find")
        return res.json({
            result: 'ok',
            message: "Add member successfully!",
        })
    }).catch(error => next(error))
}
```

But it does not work as I expected. If projectId wrong, nested method 1 in Promise not working but nested method 2 still working, the database will be updated. The same as userId wrong.

How can I return error when once wrong?

Comment: Don't start them at the same time to run them concurrently if you want one to depend on the other.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you want to only update user when project update is successful, for that Promise.all is not the solution, chain the promises, like

```
Project.findByIdAndUpdate(projectId, { $push: {members: userId}})
    .then(()=>{
            return  User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { $push: {projects: { id: userId, role: role}} });
        })
    .then(values => {
        if (!values[0] || !values[1]) return next("Can not find")
        return res.json({
        result: 'ok',
        message: "Add member successfully!",
    })
 }).catch(error => next(error))
```

Comment: It's wrong when userId wrong, projectId true, Project.findByIdAndUpdate() working but User.findByIdAndUpdate() not working.

Comment: @NguyenVanTuan You should've been more clear about that in your question

Answer (score 0):

> Rather than calling `findByIdAndUpdate` functions in the
>   `Promise.all` block. You can split the code in to two parts.

1) Define `findById` function which only check if the record exists and an `update` function to update the entries

2) execute the `findById` and `update` codes in the `Promise.all` separately.

```
const addMember = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { userId, role, projectId } = req.body

    Promise.all([
      Project.findById(projectId, { $push: {members: userId}}),
      User.findById(userId, { $push: {projects: { id: userId, role: role}} })
    ]).then(values => {
        if (!values[0] || !values[1]) return next("Can not find")

        Promise.all([
          Project.update(projectId, { $push: {members: userId}}),
          User.update(userId, { $push: {projects: { id: userId, role: role}} })
        ]).then(values => {
          return res.json({
            result: 'ok',
            message: "Add member successfully!",
          })
        })
    }).catch(error => next(error))
}
```